# UnicodeEncodeError on Linux but not on Windows

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, unicode

I'm getting an `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode` exception when I try to print a Unicode string on Linux. On Windows I do not get the error.

The code executed on Linux:

```
    my_str = u'\u4ece\u5165\u5e93'
    print "%r"  % my_str #output: u'\u4ece\u5165\u5e93' 
    print "%s" % my_str #output: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u4ece' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

On Windows I get:

```
    my_str = u'\u4ece\u5165\u5e93'
    print "%r"  % my_str #output: u'\u4ece\u5165\u5e93' 
    print "%s" % my_str #output: 从入库
```

Comment: What is the value of `import sys; sys.stdout.encoding`? `print` must encode Unicode values to the locale of your terminal or pipe.

Comment: utf-8 ,and I find that if I just python thefile.py it can work well，but If I use it  with other people project，it will be get error

Comment: Then please provide a *reproducable example*. It sounds as if you are using a pipe or subprocess, in which case the default is ASCII. Set the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable to override.

Comment: Voting to reopen because the question (and answers) are quite different to the claimed duplicate. The discussion of `locale` here is very useful. This question seems to be more about _why_ one gets the error, whereas the alleged duplicate is about _how_ to change the encoding settings.

Answer (score 10):

It's very likely that your `locale` and/or environment is broken, not installed, not set or set to `C`. Python uses the locale settings to apply the correct encoder on stdout. This allows Unicodes to be encoded to the appropriate encoding.

If you're running Python from the command line, make sure your locale is healthy. Type `locale` and your should see something like:

```
 $ locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
 $
```

If you see error messages or if LANG=C or similar, Python will use an ASCII encoder, which rejects non-ASCII characters.

To find the locales installed on your system, type `locale -a`. Select the appropriate locale, ideally one ending in "UTF-8", and set `LANG` accordingly. E.g.

```
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
```

The run `locale` again and check for errors. If you still get errors then you will need to research how to rebuild your locales for your distribution.

If you're running within an IDE or you're unable to fix your then you may have success with adding the following environment variable to your shell or IDE run configuration:

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
```

This tells Python to ignore the locale and apply a UTF-8 encoder to stdout.

You can validate what Python is using for the locale by using the `locale` module in Python. My healthy locale returns:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.getdefaultlocale()
('en_GB', 'UTF-8')
>>> locale.getpreferredencoding()
'UTF-8'
```

An unhealthy locale will return `US-ASCII` for `locale.getpreferredencoding()`

Comment: thanks， locale.getdefaultlocale() output-> 
('en_US', 'UTF8')

Comment: Your locale is broken. It should be `UTF-8` with a hyphen and match the definition in `locale -a`.  Do: `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`, then run `locale` to verify

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack: in this case, the OP is almost certainly using a pipe, in which case there is no terminal and Python defaults to ASCII.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack thanks，but if I just execute the py file seperately, it works well, but if   I use the file work with my friend's project, I get errors. There some clue: My friend some works on linux and some works on windows

Comment: As @MartijnPieters has asked, you need to provide more details and not just the small sample provided. Are you piping within the shell. I.e. `cat "data" | python my_script.py`?

Comment: sorry about ignorant of mine, I don't what's the "data" stand for. And I find when I print "你好" on the linux system, it works fine, but print u"你好" get error.

Comment: And the key is not print correctly, but the error @MartijnPieters@Alastair McCormack

Comment: @Helpme123 that is because one is *encoded bytes*, the other Unicode. Take a look at http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html to learn more about the difference.

Comment: This is the correct answer, been struggling with that issue, the problem was locale settings

Answer (score -1):

you can try:

```
print u"{0}".format(str)
```

or

```
print u"{0}".format(l.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: This is not an issue with how the interpolated value is converted, because it isn't. `bytestr % (unicodestring,)` will implicitly *decode* the bytestring, which works for the OP because `"%s"` only contains ASCII characters. The OP has an *encoding* exception however, because the `print` statement has to encode the resulting unicode value to `sys.stdout.encoding`.